# GROUP BY and take the given value if it is not empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table

```
+-----+-----------+-----+
| ID  | NAME      | LOC |
+-----+-----------+-----+
| 101 | Stainless | NY  |
| 101 | Brass     | MUM |
| 102 |           | NY  |
| 102 | Gold      | JP  |
| 103 | Silver    | CN  |
| 103 | Aluminium | US  |
| 104 | Platinum  | NY  |
| 104 | Diamond   | UK  |
| 105 |           | NY  |
+-----+-----------+-----+
```

I want to `group by` and take the `NAME` correspoding to `NY` location. If the `NAME` is empty for `NY` then take the other one. Incase if `NY` is not available for any `ID`, then take any `NAME` from other locations. And if some ID is present only once with empty `NAME`, then we can take the same.

Expected output

```
+-----+-----------+
| ID  | NAME      |
+-----+-----------+
| 101 | Stainless |
| 102 | Gold      |
| 103 | Silver    |
| 104 | Platinum  |
| 105 |           |
+-----+-----------+
```

I have tried the below query. But it is not giving my expected output. What am i missing?

```
SELECT ID, MAX(CASE WHEN LOC='NY' AND NAME!='' THEN NAME END) NAME
FROM MYTABLE  
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: In your expected outcome for ID = 104 shouldn't the name = Platinum  instead of Diamond?

Comment: @SaiAbhiramInapala. You are right. Updated my question

Comment: Why would 102 be GOLD?

Comment: Because `NAME` corresonding to `NY` is empty for `102` @mrivanlima. As mentioned in question, if it is empty take the `NAME` from other location

Comment: Ok, I believe I understand that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation like this:

```
select id,
       coalesce( max(case when location = 'NY' then name end),
                 max(name)
               ) as desired_name
from t
group by id;
```

Note:  This assumes that the blank names are really `NULL`.  If they are not then tweak the logic:

```
select id,
       coalesce( max(case when location = 'NY' and name <> '' then name end),
                 max(name)
               ) as desired_name
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `row_number()` - **[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ca6ca5b055b1b91732bbc3854413278)**

```
select * from
(
SELECT *,
row_number() over(partition by id order by case when NAME='' then -1 when LOC='NY' AND NAME!='' then 1 else 0 end desc) as rn
FROM t 
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks. There is one problem here. There are some `ID` which are present only once with empty `NAME`. In that case, those IDs are not coming from the above query. I'm really sorry I didn't notice this scenario before.  Updated my question.

Comment: @Avinash, I've updated the answer - you can check now

Answer (score 1):

Please do thorough testing before relying on the given script as it is based on the given tiny sample of data.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, LOC
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID
            ) AS run
    FROM Table_1
    WHERE ID NOT IN (
            SELECT ID
            FROM Table_1
            WHERE LOC = 'NY' AND Name IS NOT NULL
            ) AND NAME IS NOT NULL
    ) A
WHERE run = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM Table_1
WHERE LOC = 'NY' AND Name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ID
```